# Why do I receive e-mails from Pinterest for an unverified account?

Tags: pinterest

I have created an account on Pinterest, because I haven't actually been aware of the purpose for which other uses this site. As I learned it (seconds after registration), I decided not to use it and thus **I haven't confirmed my e-mail** -- i.e. I didn't click anything in confirmation e-mail sent by Pinterest and send that e-mail to my bin.

Even though I'm 100% sure, that neither I nor anyone else has confirmed my Pinterest account / e-mail address I keep getting "Pinterest Weekly" and all other e-mails from Pinterest for my account.

What am I missing? Shouldn't any unconfirmed account be deleted after a certain period of time? Isn't sending e-mails to an unconfirmed e-mail address a violation of very basic antispam rule? And finally -- isn't this an actual spam?

Comment: Technically, no, it's probably not spam, because you've already given them your email address, even if you haven't followed through to confirm that the address belongs to you. Pinterest is a pretty above-board outfit; I'm sure that there's an "unsubscribe" link in their messages. I think you'll be safe using that.

Comment: "...because you've already given them your email address" - and probably had to accept the T&Cs and privacy policy (which might have included such clauses) before registering. (?)

Comment: just unsubscribe and go back to pinterest to delete the account

Comment: Guys, what are you talking about? If they send anything to e-mail address provided, but unverified, then this is a pure spam. How can they may difference, if this is I, who gave them my e-mail address? Maybe this is my ugly neighbor, who want to make my life a little bit more miserable? Or just a stupid spammer, who enters mine or anyone else e-mail just because he/she can? Thousands of services for more than ten years sends a verification e-mail with notice: "If someone else used your address, then please ignore this message, your account will be deleted soon". Pinterest tries to go opposite?